# How to Change the URL Hyperlink in Current Page Based On User's Previous Page?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I would like to create a "404 Not Found" page and add a URL link in the page based on user's previous page.

For example, let say our domain is "www.example.com". If a user is currently visiting a resource in our domain such as "www.example.com/products", and then go to "www.example.com/pageDoesntExist", the server will return "404 Not Found" together with a go back link that will take the user back to "www.example.com/products".

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back</button>
```

However, if a user is currently visiting resource outside of our domain, such as "www.google.com" or any other site, and when the user visit "www.example.com/pageDoesntExist", the server will return "404 Not Found" together with a link that will take the user to our home page "www.example.com".

```
<a href="/">Go to Example.com</a>
```

Is there a way to switch between these two links based on the user's previous visited page? Only one of the link should be rendered on server, instead of using browser's JS to determine.

Comment: I think the current behavior is what’s needed. You intend the link to take the user back to google instead?

Comment: No, if the user come from outside example.com, then I intend to take the user to the example.com home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.referrer` to determine the path which user come from.Then according to referrer decision routing

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. What if I want to render the link on the server instead of using browser's JS to determine the link? How do you access `document.referrer` on the server?

Comment: I didn't handle this on the server.
If you don't want to use js to judge, you can redirect the 404 page to a php page, and then use php to determine.

Comment: Yup, I am just wondering if it is possible for the server to determine the page? How do you do it?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] will give you the referrer page's URL if there exists any.  [404-error-with-any-php-file-using-nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126555/404-error-with-any-php-file-using-nginx?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Didn't know they have `http referrer`. That's what I am looking for. Thanks!